# Do actors actually carry actresses?

Tags: stunts

I've seen a lot of movies where the actor (and sometimes actress) will carry another person bridal-style. Are they actually lifting the other person or are they carrying a dummy that looks like the person?

Comment: Er, if you see the face of the person being carried, it's probably real. Why is it such a stretch that people are carried around in movies? It's usually not that dangerous a stunt.

Comment: if it's a woman carrying a man, it's an Effortless Amazonian Lift (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EffortlessAmazonianLift)

Comment: That is one talented (and real) dummy!

Answer (score 1):

Probably real.

The effort of carrying a person is probably smaller than that of dressing up a dummy to look real.